# How to make Modules use Application View Helpers?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-view

Since, adding some extra modules to the zend framework application, a lot of errors are popping out. By default, all the extra modules tend to use the same layout file to render a html, but for view helpes, it searches it's own folder.

In my case, I made a view helper, to load some template's css file. I named it `LoadTemplate` and placed it inside `APPLICATION_PATH."/view/helpers"`

It works perfectly, until I browse to a module. Then it gives a error saying

```
Plugin by name 'LoadTemplate' was not found in the registry; used paths: Custom_View_Helper_: x/x/application/modules/custom/views\helpers/ Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/
```

It is searching in the wrong folder.

Can't we tell it to search its folder first, and if not found go and find the helper from the default or Application's View Helper?

Comment: It should do this anyway. All view helpers are located by the central view plugin loader. Perhaps show some examples of what is and is not working

Comment: @Phil, I have updated my question a bit, may be its a little bit more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If your helper is in that directory, make sure it is called `Zend_View_Helper_LoadTemplate`, the function is called `loadTemplate` and the file name is `LoadTemplate.php`

Edit -

Also check out this blog post by Rob Allen: http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/view-helpers-in-modules/